# Why the group order has to be prime for pairing-based cryptography

Tags: pairings

I'm trying to get into pairing-based cryptography and I don't see why the group order of the group G in  the pairing function

e:G*G-> G_t

has to be a prime number.

I don't find an argument why groups of order p^k for a prime number p and some entire number k cannot be used?

Comment: Where did you read that it has to be prime?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography
as well in the video right here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4x2kQTKYFY
in the beginning (+- 4th minute)

Comment: Check out [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/when-do-we-need-composite-order-groups-for-bilinear-maps-and-when-prime-order) and the  two answers with upvotes. Especially [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3887/706) as I think it answers your question.

Comment: @mikeazo Thank you very much! So from a mathematical (theoretical) point of view it doesnt matter if it is a primer order or a power of a prime order. the main reason to use prime numbers is to speed up calculations. Furthermore we can most of the time pass from a prime-power order to a prime order groups.